# jQuery fadeIn without fadeOut?

Tags: jquery, css, fadein, fadeout

So basically I'm trying to reproduce [this effect](http://jsfiddle.net/buSae/165/) but I cannot figure out how to constantly "fadeIn" on picture after the other, without the fadeOut to white (I want the next image to blend-in).

```
var run = function() {
    transition();
    slideshow.fadeIn('slow', function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            slideshow.fadeOut('slow', run);
        }, timeToDisplay);
    });
}
```

I've tried replacing fadeOut by fadeIn but it doesn't work. Any ideas ?

Comment: Will [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z4dd1bg4/) do the job for you?

Comment: That's the effect I want, but I don't want to have multiple divs, I want the same div to change of background-image url with a fadeIn effect. Thanks!

Comment: There won't be any way to do it with only one div. with one div if you do not fadeout to 0 opacity, and change the image, the user will see a jump between the image changings. Why you can not use multiple divs? what if you create the internal divs dynamically in the javascript code and inject them in your html? still not acceptable for you?

Comment: Yes, I might go with multiple divs as you suggest. Thank you very much for your time and help, it's really appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the fadeIn only. So change fadeOut to fadeIn.

```
var run = function() {
    transition();
    slideshow.fadeIn('slow', function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            slideshow.fadeIn('slow', run);
        }, timeToDisplay);
    });
}
```

(Here is your fiddle)[ https://jsfiddle.net/yonashailug/q8ebgm75 ]

Comment: The fiddle provided is a 404!

Comment: @EhsanT I have change the fadeOut inside the fadeIn function is changed to fadeIn and I am updating the fiddle sorry.

Comment: Still it's 404. Please remove the **]** at the end of the link. But I do not think your is what the OP is looking for. I think he still needs the fading, but not from complete white. As he said, he needs somehow blending the images one after each other

Comment: Thank you guys. That's what I had tried before, but that way there is no blending effect. Any other suggestion ?

Comment: I get `transition is not defined` error

Answer (score -1):

3 years late but you can solve it using css display: none on the element you want to fade in

Then in document.ready() you call fadeIn()

CSS:

```
body {
      display: none;
    }
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  $("body").fadeIn(2000);
})
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/3gpzcjn9/